# Free Monad of a Monad

Tags: haskell, free-monad

Is `x >>= f` equivalent to `retract (liftF x >>= liftF . f)`?

That is, is the monad instance of a free monad build from a Functor which is also a Monad going to have an equivalent monad instance to the original Monad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what your definition of `retract` is, but given

```
retract :: Monad m => Free m a -> m a
retract (Pure a) = return a
retract (Impure fx) = fx >>= retract
```

and

```
liftF :: Functor f => f a -> Free f a
liftF fx = Impure (fmap Pure fx)
```

note that (proofs might be wrong, did them by hand and haven't checked them)

```
retract $ liftF x
= retract (Impure (fmap Pure x))
= (fmap Pure x) >>= retract
= (x >>= return . Pure) >>= retract
= x >>= \y -> (return $ Pure y) >>= retract
= x >>= \y -> (retract (Pure y))
= x >>= \y -> return y
= x >>= return
= x
```

so you have

```
retract (liftF x >>= liftF . f)
= retract ((Impure (fmap Pure x)) >>= liftF . f)
= retract $ Impure $ fmap (>>= liftF . f) $ fmap Pure x
= (fmap (>>= liftF . f) $ fmap Pure x) >>= retract
= (fmap (\y -> Pure y >>= liftF . f) x) >>= retract
= (fmap (liftF . f) x) >>= retract
= (liftM (liftF . f) x) >>= retract
= (x >>= return . liftF . f) >>= retract
= x >>= (\y -> (return $ liftF $ f y >>=  retract)
= x >>= (\y -> retract $ liftF $ f y)
= x >>= (\y -> retract . liftF $ f y)
= x >>= (\y -> f y)
= x >>= f
```

this does not mean that `Free m a` is isomorphic to `m a`, just that `retract` is really witness to a retraction.  Note that `liftF` is *not* a monad morphism (`return` does not go to `return`).  Free is functor in the category of functors, but it is not a monad in the category of monads (despite `retract` looking a lot like `join` and `liftF` looking a lot like `return`).

EDIT: Note that the retraction implies a sort of equivalence.  Define

```
 ~ : Free m a -> Free m a -> Prop
 a ~ b = (retract a) ==_(m a) (retract b)
```

Then consider the quotient type `Free m a/~`.  I assert that this type is isomorphic to `m a`.   Since `(liftF (retract x)) ~ x` because `(retract . liftF . retract $ x) ==_(m a) retract x`.  Thus, the free monad over a monad is exactly that monad plus some extra data.  This is exactly the same as the claim that `[m]` is "essentially the same" as `m` when `m` is `m` is a monoid.

Comment: Great answer, this really explores the nature of the equivalence, and hints at constraints on the ways that you can make two different monads out of the same functor

Comment: "Note that liftF is not a monad morphism (return does not go to return)" but return *does* go to return under `retract`.  So they're not isomorphic because you can distinguish them, but under retract they becomes indistinguishable again?

Comment: @singpolyma exactly.  If you quotient out by things equivalent after `retract` they are isomorphic.   Otherwise it is just a retraction.  Which interpretation you want depends on what you are doing, but for some applications you would really like to use `Free` over some functor `f` but need a monad transformer.  The obvious way to get such a transformer is to consider `Free (f :+: m)` but this is not a transformer since `liftF` etc are not monad morphisms.  A good example of this is `Pipes`.  You can distinguish them, so if you want to do this wrap it in a module/don't export constructors.

Answer (score 4):

> That is, is the monad instance of a free monad build from a Functor which is also a Monad going to have an equivalent monad instance to the original Monad?

No. The free monad over *any* functor is a monad. Thus, it cannot magically know about the Monad instance when it exists. And it cannot also "guess" it, because the same functor may be made a Monad in different ways (e.g. a writer monad for different monoids).

Another reason is that it doesn't make much sense to ask whether these two monads have equivalent instances because they are not even isomorphic as types. For example, consider the free monad over the writer monad. It will be a list-like structure. What does it mean for these two instances to be equivalent?

### Example of different monad instances

In case the above description isn't clear, here's an example of a type with many possible Monad instances.

```
data M a = M Integer a

bindUsing :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
bindUsing f (M n a) k =
  let M m b = k a
  in M (f m n) b

-- Any of the below instances is a valid Monad instance
instance Monad M where
  return x = M 0 x
  (>>=) = bindUsing (+)

instance Monad M where
  return x = M 1 x
  (>>=) = bindUsing (*)
```

Comment: if you treat `Impure (a,mzero)` as being equal to `a` you have that they are the same--which you probably should most of the time.

Comment: Did you mean `mempty` instead of `mzero`? Still don't see how they are the same.

Comment: yes,  Given the quotienting that `Impure (a,mzero) = a` it is trivial to `Free (Writer m) a` is isomorphic to `Writer m a`.  `Free (Writer m) a = Writer [m] a`, and if what you care about is the monoidal structure, those look similar. They are not the same in that you can write a function to tell them apart, on the other hand, the are the same in that you probably shouldn't :).

Comment: `[m]` is not the same as `m` by any standard. You can get from `[m]` to `m` by using `mconcat` (and that's the point of the free monad — you can get from it to any other monad), but they are not isomorphic (you can't recover `[m]` from `m`).

Comment: I don't disagree.  That is what makes it a *retraction* not an isomorphism.  Just that most of the time you really want to consider `Free m a` as "the same" as `m a` and `[m]` as "the same" as `m`.  This can be formalized easily using quotient types (which we can only pretend exist in Haskell) and is the basis for doing things like using free monads to implement efficient `Pipes` even though that implementation does not obey the transformer laws (because `lift` is not a monad morphism) even though you don't have the quotienting that makes this "safe" in Haskell.

Comment: Note that your argument in this answer "it can't guess the structure" is not strong enough, even though your conclusion is true in this case.  `data FreeFunctor f a = forall b. FreeFunctor (f b) (b -> a)` is a Functor and isomorphic to `f a` whenever `f` is a `Functor`.

Comment: «your argument in this answer "it can't guess the structure" is not strong enough» — my argument was that there may be more than one possible Monad instance. This is not true for Functor — hence, the conclusion is also not true for Functor.

Comment: The more than on possible Monad instance seems like it would break this idea.  Do you have a good example?  Write over different monoids is not a different instance, and indeed works as I originally expected.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka That's nice, but the `retract`ion still uses the underlying `Monad` instance. `Free` monads ought to always be larger than any other monad defined on a functor. The retraction should be the unique mapping that makes `Free` universal, no?

Comment: I think @tel is right.  The reason we end up back at the correct `Monad` instance is because of how `retract` is implemented.

Comment: Sure, I don't object that — that's why the free monad is free (as I've already written above). What I object to is saying that `Free m` is in any sense *equivalent* to `m`.

Comment: Hm. I just re-read your question, and I might have misunderstood it. I thought that you were asking about the usual monad instance of Free. If, instead, you were asking about a possibility to define an alternative Monad instance for Free which mimics the instance of the original Monad, then your question starts (and my answer stops :) to make sense. Sorry for confusion then.